# require is not defined at npm.js:2

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Forgive me if this is something simple as my research has come up empty in regards to this specific issue. I am using Bootstrap the most recent release. I have noticed that there is a file that is new from previous releases called npm.js. I am hosting all the Bootstrap files locally on my hosted web server. I call the file like all the others in the head to the full path to the file. In the console I have this error.

> npm.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at npm.js:2

Which is referring to this line.

```
require('../../js/transition.js')`
```

Which is from this npm.js file that is in the newest Bootstrap

```
// This file is autogenerated via the `commonjs` Grunt task. You can require() this file in a CommonJS environment.
require('../../js/transition.js')
require('../../js/alert.js')
require('../../js/button.js')
require('../../js/carousel.js')
require('../../js/collapse.js')
require('../../js/dropdown.js')
require('../../js/modal.js')
require('../../js/tooltip.js')
require('../../js/popover.js')
require('../../js/scrollspy.js')
require('../../js/tab.js')
require('../../js/affix.js')
```

I am unfamilar with this so I am not sure why I am getting this error but, how can I surpress this error and fix this issue? Do I even need this file? From what I understand if I am using modals or tooltips etc I need this. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download/config the missing libraries or requires. I am not sure which libraries you are using. 
You can add the missing libraries to your package.json. Then call for npm install.

Comment: I am not sure where I would download/config the missing libraries or requires as it was not included in the Bootstrap download. Do I really need the npm.js in order to use all the features of Bootstrap? I.E. Modals, tooltips, transitions, collapse, button, alert etc?

Comment: This depends on whether you need these libraries. If you do not need any of them, there is no need to require it. 

I am not completely aware of your dev env, but possibly, you may not need npm. 
In case you do, If you have a package.json file, then you can add your devDependencies or dependencies. Then, in the cmd, you call for "npm install" to have them installed into your node_modules folder.

Comment: In order to search for a version of a library, you can try this command:
npm the-name-of-the-library version

Alternatively, you can download libraries manually and place them under the file structure your specified in your requires; i.e. '../../js/transition.js'

Comment: As well, when you call for
,,/,,/

This means that these libraries are located in upper hierarchy by two levels.

Comment: I think this is where the confusion is coming in on my part. I am not running my own web server. I use a hosted solution. In this case Bluehost. So I don't have access to Linux commands. I do need modals, collapse, alert etc though. This all worked fine previously to V4 of Bootstrap since this npm.js file is new with the new download.

Comment: Maybe, the issue is related to "require()" being not defined in the client side. 

Make sure that you use the script tag to use CommonJS implementation on the client-side. 
<script src="js/common.js"></script>